# how to find the value by param id in View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a field in the View like,

```
<%= f.text_field :question_id, class: "cross-reference-question-value"  %>
```

Now, I tried to use this `question_id` that match the other column from the same table like the following:

```
<%= text_field :question_id, Question2009.all.map{|an| [an.answer_table]} %>
```

I could get all the values here from that table. But, I just need to get the value that match the `params` of `question_id`.

Comment: You are trying to put an array in a text_field? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Another one from vinay :) 
Vinay be more specific in your questions. 
Is this what you are looking for Question2009.where(:question_id => params[:questionid]).answer_table

Comment: @Ross - yeah. I need to get the value of answer_table where question_id = the user selected the question_id in the previous field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<%= text_field :question_id, Question2009.all.map{|an| [an.answer_table]} %>
```

To

```
<%= text_field :question_id, Question2009.where("question_id=?", params[:question_id]).map{|an| [an.answer_table]} %>
```

Comment: Got an error .. undefined local variable or method `question_id' for #<#<Class:0xa1d0024>:0xd48f7a8>

Comment: That should be `params[:question_id]`.